# Docker setup for Wordpress development

Tags: wordpress, docker

I am trying to figure out how to setup a Wordpress development environment with Docker, such that.

1) I have a wordpress theme I wish to share via a docker image with colleagues.
2) I wish to save all data related to modifications to siad theme and changes I make to Wordpress at development time in the Docker Image so that they can get up and running with developing it further. 
3) I wish to know the mechanism for them to save the data back to Docker and store the resulting file in source control (Github).

At the moment, I've been able to setup a Docker file that runs with `docker-compose up` - but it doesn't save any changes made to the database, or (I more specifically I don't currently know how to do that). Reading the docs, it looks like I possibly need to 'docker commit' and then export the resulting image?

Bit confused with the concepts etc at the minute, so any help appreciated.

```
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wordpress
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:5.1.1-php7.3-apache
    ports:
      - "8001"
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    volumes:
      - ./wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
      - ./uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
volumes:
  db_data:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you share your compose file? You can mount volumes into the wordpress docker container. Then you'd have the wordpress files in your normal FileSystem, which you then can add to Git. Mounting goes as follows:

```
 volumes:
       - /var/www/html/:/var/www/html
```

In order to safe your Wordpress Container, you need to Tag it via `docker tag {id of wp container} your/repo:{Tag you want to add, for exmaple v1 or v2...}` and then push your container to the hub cloud via `docker push your/repo:{your tag}`. From there on, your mates can pull the image from the hub and run it with all the new changes.

Hope this helps,
Greetings

€: You can then just add the /wp-content folder in your yml directory to git. Also mount the db_data to a folder. Add the 3th line to your yml:

```
volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

Comment: added the yml file there.

Comment: so mounting the db_data to a folder, is that then sharable (data wise) when someone else runs it from the hub?

Comment: yes, all of your data will be inside that folder. When you pass this folder to somebody else hell have the exact same db

Answer (score 0):

To share database data, add `volumes` option in `db` service.

```yaml
db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
      MYSQL_USER: wpuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: '1'
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/mysql
```

In most cases (develop themes or plugins), just `wp-content/themes` and `wp-content/plugins` are enough.

I developed a github project useful to share all data with other developers in team for that using `docker-compose` based on official wordpress image.

[HERE IS GITHUB](https://github.com/molavec/docker-wordpress)